# Is it possible to dynamically update systemd-timer's onCalendar?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer, calendar, events, system-programming

`sytemd-timer` has a feature "onCalendar" using which we can execute a script on points of time (on calendar).

Is it possible to dynamically (programmatically) update or mutate that field?
For example consider this application:
1- Executing a script (as a pre-task) and finding out the new date intervals that the main script should be run.
2- Updating the corresponding systemd-timer to use the new date (calendar) intervals.

If it's not possible with systemd, how can we do it?

Comment: You can have your script generate an override file for the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your timer is `/etc/systemd/system/foo.timer`, then you can create a file `/etc/systemd/system/foo.timer.d/override.conf` with the contents

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=...
```

which will override the `OnCalendar` specification from `/etc/systemd/system/foo.timer`. It might be necessary to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing `override.conf`.